# Can I install .Net Framework and .Net Core on the same machine?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Is there any restriction, or something I need pay attention to when install both of them in the same machine?

Comment: Yes. Case closed! Depends on the platform. Only windows supports the .NET framework, but .NET core is the core framework that runs platform independently.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

.NET Framework installations are machine-global. e.g. if you update a machine from .NET Framework 4.5.2 to .NET Framework 4.6, *all* .NET Framework apps on the machine now run on 4.6.

.NET Core installations are completely independent from the version of .NET Framework. In fact, you can actually install multiple version of .NET Core side-by-side on the same machine (unlike .NET Framework). Each app can determine which version of .NET Core to use.