# .NET Core Runtime without installing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-server-2012

Can anyone help as to how to use the run time binaries found in the link below?
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Basically, we are moving to .NET Core (we have been using .NET framework 4.0 for many years - so big shift as you can guess). I am kind of nervous to install .NET core on the production server (Windows Server 2012). Is it safe to install .NET Core on a server running .NET framework 4.0? If no, is there any way I can get the .NET Core runtime on to the server without installing them (kind of copying portal libraries) so that I can start with the beta testing of the app. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
It is not duplicate, One of the main questions I had if I can use portable binaries on the server to run my app, without actually installing them (got the answer below, thanks again). Not sure someone down voted this without any reason. It makes the developers nervous to ask a question in StackOverflow. if they can mention the reason that would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install .Net Framework and .Net Core on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410042/can-i-install-net-framework-and-net-core-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no issues when installing .NET Core and .NET Framework on the same machine. They are designed to allow them to be installed side-by-side.

However you do need to install the .NET Core runtime onto the server to allow the code to be run because the OS has native dependencies that need to be present. See [this link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Jun/05/Which-NET-Core-Runtime-Download-do-you-need#net-core-runtimes) for more information.

With .NET Core you can do framework dependent deployments (FDD) and self-contained deployments (SCD). FDD requires any shared assemblies to be present on the server i.e. System.* assemblies etc. but an SCD only requires the basic runtime/native dependencies. For an SCD your app deployment would include any .NET Core shared assemblies in it's deployment package.

You can read more about FDD and SCD [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

Also there is more information about the native dependencies on different OS platforms [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/prereqs.md)